# transform from odom,map to base_link

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello ,
i have changed base_link name to mock_base_link for changing axes of robot model in urdf  now i have to do gmapping but i have issue transform is not happening to other links
'odom
No transform from [odom] to frame [base_link]
similar to map also

i have used

```
 <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="mock2base" args="0 0 0 -1.57 0 0 mock_base_link base_link 20" />
```

in launch file

[image: image description]

thanks a ton

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333320/transform-from-odom,map-to-base_link/) by [kallivalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/42408/kallivalli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2019-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your TF tree doesn't show a base_link frame at all, which tells me that while your publishing mock_base_link -> base_link, there's nothing publishing the base_link frame or a completed tree of base_link -> odom.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kallivalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/42408/kallivalli/) on 2019-09-19**:
i changed name of base_link to mock_base_link in urdf to change my axes position of my robot model  and published static tf and also i tried changing in urdf but unsuccesfull so how can i do mapping ?